# Rails 6, can not get s3_direct_upload gem to UPLOAD, view works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems

I have 2 apps I have re-written from older versions of Rails (3.2 and 4.2.1) to Rails v6.1.4.1 and they both use the s3_direct_upload gem.

On Both apps I do not get any errors in the Webdev console or in the Rails console or in the log or ANYPLACE I can find.  The buckets are displaying just fine in the case of Both Apps.
I checked the CORS Setup and it is fine.  Both of these apps are currently running on Heroku with the code the same way it is now but are working.

Does anyone know if the s3_direct_upload gem actually works with Rails 6?

I get the file select window, I choose the filename, it shows the filename but instead of it starting the upload and showing the progress bar it just acts as if I did nothing at that point.  No errors no nothing anyplace I can find.  When I have the original app side by side at that point I should see a quick progress bar come up and then go away, the page refreshes and shows the new file.  IN the 2 Apps I have re-written, it never gets past the file select and showing the file name of what I have selected.  I will show the general files so at least that can be seen:

So that is question 1, does the s3_direct_upload gem work in Rails 6?

Here are the basic files that are required:

s3_direct_upload.rb

```
S3DirectUpload.config do |c|
  c.access_key_id     = Rails.configuration.aws[:access_key_id]
  c.secret_access_key = Rails.configuration.aws[:secret_access_key]
  c.bucket            = Rails.configuration.aws[:bucket]
  c.region            = "ENV['AWS_REGION']"
  c.url               = "https://#{c.bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/" 
end
```

aws.rb

```
require 'aws-sdk-v1'
# Rails.configuration.aws is used by AWS, Paperclip, and S3DirectUpload
Rails.configuration.aws = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml")).result)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys!
AWS.config(logger: Rails.logger)
AWS.config(Rails.configuration.aws)
```

paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  url:                  ":s3_domain_url",
  path:                 ":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  storage:              :s3,
  s3_credentials:       Rails.configuration.aws,
  s3_permissions:       :private,
  s3_protocol:          "https",
  s3_region:            ENV["AWS_REGION"]
)
```

aws.rb

```
require 'aws-sdk-v1'
# Rails.configuration.aws is used by AWS, Paperclip, and S3DirectUpload
Rails.configuration.aws = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml")).result)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys!
AWS.config(logger: Rails.logger)
AWS.config(Rails.configuration.aws)
```

aws.yml  (I changed the bucket names to mybucket, the pictures work so I know the bucket works)

```
defaults: &defaults
development:
  <<: *defaults
  region: <%=ENV["AWS_REGION"]%> 
  bucket: "mybucket"
  access_key_id: <%=ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_DPFR"]%>
  secret_access_key: <%=ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY_DPFR"]%>
test:
  <<: *defaults
  region: <%=ENV["AWS_REGION"]%> 
  bucket: "mybucket-test"
production:
  region: <%=ENV["AWS_REGION"]%> 
  access_key_id: <%=ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_DPFR"]%>
  secret_access_key: <%=ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY_DPFR"]%>
  bucket: "mybucket"
```

Here are the relevant gems:  (If someone wants to see the entire gemfile let me know)

```
gem 'paperclip-aws', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.8'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1', '~> 1.67'
gem 's3_direct_upload', '~> 0.1.7'
```

And here is the relevant js s3_direct_upload.js.coffee. (I even tried converting to strait JS vs the coffee and no difference.  The alert is in there because I wanted to be sure it was reading the file and it does I get the alert.

```
#= require jQuery-fileupload/basic
#= require jQuery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl

alert("We are in the S3_Direct_Upload coffee file");



$ = jQuery

$.fn.S3Uploader = (options) ->

  # support multiple elements
  if @length > 1
    @each ->
      $(this).S3Uploader options

    return this

  $uploadForm = this

  settings =
    path: ''
    additional_data: null
    before_add: null
    remove_completed_progress_bar: true
    remove_failed_progress_bar: false
    progress_bar_target: null
    click_submit_target: null
    allow_multiple_files: true
    dropZone: null

  $.extend settings, options

  current_files = []
  forms_for_submit = []
  if settings.click_submit_target
    settings.click_submit_target.click ->
      form.submit() for form in forms_for_submit
      false

  $wrapping_form = $uploadForm.closest('form')
  if $wrapping_form.length > 0
    $wrapping_form.off('submit').on 'submit', ->
      $wrapping_form.find('.s3_uploader input').prop "disabled", true
      true

  setUploadForm = ->
    $uploadForm.find("input[type='file']").fileupload

      dropZone: settings.dropzone_target
      add: (e, data) ->
        file = data.files[0]
        file.unique_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,16)

        unless settings.before_add and not settings.before_add(file)
          current_files.push data
          if $('#template-upload').length > 0
            data.context = $($.trim(tmpl("template-upload", file)))
            $(data.context).appendTo(settings.progress_bar_target || $uploadForm)
          else if !settings.allow_multiple_files
            data.context = settings.progress_bar_target
          if settings.click_submit_target
            if settings.allow_multiple_files
              forms_for_submit.push data
            else
              forms_for_submit = [data]
          else
            data.submit()

      start: (e) ->
        $uploadForm.trigger("s3_uploads_start", [e])

      progress: (e, data) ->
        if data.context
          progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
          data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')

      done: (e, data) ->
        content = build_content_object $uploadForm, data.files[0], data.result

        callback_url = $uploadForm.data('callback-url')
        if callback_url
          content[$uploadForm.data('callback-param')] = content.url

          $.ajax
            type: $uploadForm.data('callback-method')
            url: callback_url
            data: content
            beforeSend: ( xhr, settings )       ->
              event = $.Event('ajax:beforeSend')
              $uploadForm.trigger(event, [xhr, settings])
              return event.result
            complete:   ( xhr, status )         ->
              event = $.Event('ajax:complete')
              $uploadForm.trigger(event, [xhr, status])
              return event.result
            success:    ( data, status, xhr )   ->
              event = $.Event('ajax:success')
              $uploadForm.trigger(event, [data, status, xhr])
              return event.result
            error:      ( xhr, status, error )  ->
              event = $.Event('ajax:error')
              $uploadForm.trigger(event, [xhr, status, error])
              return event.result

        data.context.remove() if data.context && settings.remove_completed_progress_bar # remove progress bar
        $uploadForm.trigger("s3_upload_complete", [content])

        current_files.splice($.inArray(data, current_files), 1) # remove that element from the array
        $uploadForm.trigger("s3_uploads_complete", [content]) unless current_files.length

      fail: (e, data) ->
        content = build_content_object $uploadForm, data.files[0], data.result
        content.error_thrown = data.errorThrown

        data.context.remove() if data.context && settings.remove_failed_progress_bar # remove progress bar
        $uploadForm.trigger("s3_upload_failed", [content])

      formData: (form) ->
        data = $uploadForm.find("input").serializeArray()
        fileType = ""
        if "type" of @files[0]
          fileType = @files[0].type
        data.push
          name: "content-type"
          value: fileType

        key = $uploadForm.data("key")
          .replace('{timestamp}', new Date().getTime())
          .replace('{unique_id}', @files[0].unique_id)
          .replace('{cleaned_filename}', cleaned_filename(@files[0].name))
          .replace('{extension}', @files[0].name.split('.').pop())

        # substitute upload timestamp and unique_id into key
        key_field = $.grep data, (n) ->
          n if n.name == "key"

        if key_field.length > 0
          key_field[0].value = settings.path + key

        # IE <= 9 doesn't have XHR2 hence it can't use formData
        # replace 'key' field to submit form
        unless 'FormData' of window
          $uploadForm.find("input[name='key']").val(settings.path + key)
        data

  build_content_object = ($uploadForm, file, result) ->
    content = {}
    if result # Use the S3 response to set the URL to avoid character encodings bugs
      content.url            = $(result).find("Location").text()
      content.filepath       = $('<a />').attr('href', content.url)[0].pathname
    else # IE <= 9 retu      rn a null result object so we use the file object instead
      domain                 = $uploadForm.find('input[type=file]').data('url')
      key                    = $uploadForm.find('input[name=key]').val()
      content.filepath       = key.replace('/{filename}', '').replace('/{cleaned_filename}', '')
      content.url            = domain + key.replace('/{filename}', encodeURIComponent(file.name))
      content.url            = content.url.replace('/{cleaned_filename}', cleaned_filename(file.name))

    content.filename         = file.name
    content.filesize         = file.size if 'size' of file
    content.lastModifiedDate = file.lastModifiedDate if 'lastModifiedDate' of file
    content.filetype         = file.type if 'type' of file
    content.unique_id        = file.unique_id if 'unique_id' of file
    content.relativePath     = build_relativePath(file) if has_relativePath(file)
    content = $.extend content, settings.additional_data if settings.additional_data
    content

  cleaned_filename = (filename) ->
    filename.replace(/\s/g, '_').replace(/[^\w.-]/gi, '')

  has_relativePath = (file) ->
    file.relativePath || file.webkitRelativePath

  build_relativePath = (file) ->
    file.relativePath || (file.webkitRelativePath.split("/")[0..-2].join("/") + "/" if file.webkitRelativePath)

  #public methods
  @initialize = ->
    # Save key for IE9 Fix
    $uploadForm.data("key", $uploadForm.find("input[name='key']").val())

    setUploadForm()
    this

  @path = (new_path) ->
    settings.path = new_path

  @additional_data = (new_data) ->
    settings.additional_data = new_data

  @initialize()
```

I tried having webpacker server the JS files no difference, I am starting to suspect the s3_direct_upload gem doesn't work with newer rails as that is pretty much the only difference left, OR there is some configuration change that needs to be made that I haven't been able to find in the last 3 days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have EVERYTHING ELSE working on these 2 apps 100% but the pic UPLOAD.

Thank You,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm if you pull the latest version of the s3_direct_upload gem it does in fact properly upload to Amazon S3 using Rails 6, aws-sdk-v1 and Paperclip.

To do this you have to pull the s3_direct_upload as a plugin instead of a GEM and you can do this by putting this in your gemfile:

```
gem 's3_direct_upload', github: 'waynehoover/s3_direct_upload', ref: '6f6decc75fdf89888d7f729fc89f78e90d91cece'
```

They fixed a policy issue with a key starting with $utf8 that was causing a POST Error 403 in the update along with some other issues.  With that said to use the latest version you also have to had an additional entry to your file_field_tag.

```
data: { url: s3_uploader_url }
```

So for example my file_field_tag is setup as such: (I use HAML)

```
= file_field_tag(:file, id: "before_photo", multiple: true, data: { url: s3_uploader_url })
```

After using the latest version from the GIT Repository and after adding the data: attribute to the file_field_tag it then started working properly.  Upload was making to to Amazon S3 in the upload bucket.